# Parameterized INSERT with Memo and Text Fields in VBA / MS-ACCESS?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, sql-insert

I'm trying to do a simple parametrized insert with MS-Access 2007 and I keep getting the following error (3708) from `ADODB.Parameters`:

`Parameter object is improperly defined. Inconsistent or incomplete information was provided.
s'`

I have 3 parameters that get inserted into 3 fields.  They are of the following types:

- query_name: TEXT (50)
- db_id: Number (Long Integer)
- query_text: Memo

`db_id` inserts just fine, but the other two text fields result in the error above.

Below is my simple sample code:

```
Sub testz()

    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    Set conn = CurrentProject.Connection

    Dim adoCMD As ADODB.Command
    Dim adoRS As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim lRecordsAffected As Long

    On Error GoTo Err_Insert

    strSQL = "INSERT INTO queries (query_name, db_id, query_text) VALUES (?, ?, ?)"

    Set adoCMD = New ADODB.Command

    With adoCMD
        Dim test As String
        test = "tetws"
        .ActiveConnection = conn
        .CommandType = adCmdText
        .CommandText = strSQL

        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("x1", adVarChar, adParamInput) ' Doesn't work - MS ACCESS Text field
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("x2", adInteger, adParamInput) ' This works - Numeric field
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("x3", adLongVarChar, adParamInput) ' This doesn't work MS ACCESS Memo field.

        .Parameters("x1").Value = test
        .Parameters("x2").Value = 56
        .Parameters("x3").Value = test

        adoCMD.Execute adExecuteNoRecords
    End With

    If lRecordsAffected = 0 Then
        Debug.Print ("------------------------")
        Debug.Print ("ERROR QUERY not inserted:")
        Debug.Print ("database id: " & id)
        Debug.Print ("query name: " & tblName)
        Debug.Print ("strSQL: " & qryTxt)
        Debug.Print ("------------------------")
    Else

    End If

Exit_Insert:
    Set adoCMD = Nothing
    Set adoRS = Nothing

    Exit Sub

Err_Insert:
    Debug.Print "----------------"
    Debug.Print "BEGIN: Err"
    If err.Number <> 0 Then
        Msg = "Error # " & Str(err.Number) & " was generated by " _
         & err.Source & Chr(13) & "Error Line: " & Erl & Chr(13) & err.Description
        'MsgBox Msg, , "Error", err.HelpFile, err.HelpContext
        Debug.Print Msg
    End If
    Resume Exit_Insert


End Sub
```

The [following reference](http://www.carlprothman.net/?tabid=97) says that fields of the database type `MEMO`s should have a parameter type of `adLongVarChar` and that type database type `TEXT`, should have a type of `adVarChar`.

Comment: Have you tried `adLongVarWChar` and `adVarWChar` instead?

Comment: I tried both of them, assuming `LongVarWChar` is for the memo field and `adVarWChar` is for the text field, that didn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that there are two issues at play here:

1. I'm pretty sure that with the release of Jet 4.0 (and, subsequently, ACE) the required types changed to `adVarWChar` for `Text`, and and `adLongVarWChar` for `Memo` (for multi-byte character support).
2. Text parameters must have a (maximum) length defined. I don't see those in your `.CreateParameter()` calls.

Comment: I went here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/use-a-memo-field-to-store-large-amounts-of-information-HA102505209.aspx and found that memo fields are `65535` characters, adding that to my parameters seemed to make it work.  Thanks!